# React - moving render to external function, problems?

Tags: reactjs

In trying to keep my code easily reasonable I want to move my heavy rendering code to functions outside of the main render(). Will this create problems with state changes or later cause debugging/performance problems.

Pretty new at React and just want to make sure I'm not causing headaches later down the road.

A couple of Examples

```
const Example = (props) => {
  return (
      <div>
        <p>All the cool things</p>
      </div>
  );
};
```

vs.

```
const Example = (props) => {
  const renderCoolThings = (
        <p>All the cool things</p>
  )

  return (
      <div>
        {renderCoolThings()}
      </div>
  );
};
```

It seems to work fine both ways but want to make sure this is a valid approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off make sure renderCoolThings is actually a function and not just an element, but if you prefer the second option it shouldn't.  You are adding another item to the stack in the second example but that is a miniscule performance impact if it makes your code more readable.

State changes won't he an issue either as that is part of the renter chain.

I do this almost exclusively for the same reason. When scanning code it keeps things clearer and for me it makes it more clear during debugging as I can rule out parts of the chain very easily.  The challenge may be if you are passing alot of args around it can get messy but we'll worth it if it makes it clearer for you.

Comment: so something like this?  


```
  const renderCoolThings = ()=> (
        <p>All the cool things</p>
  )

```